# Carousel view vs scroll view

Tags: scrolling, slideshow

I'm working on a mobile app that allows a user to take a photo, add information about it, and then share it.

Would it be better to provide one scrolling view that contains all the information, or separate each group of information into its own "page" and make it work like a slideshow?

Comment: Do you have a mockup to share?

Comment: @Danielillo if you mean a mockup for my app, not yet i'm working on scatching it.